# Access group row ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

When using the row [grouping](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/) feature provided by the ag-Grid, there is inserted a new 'row' as the header of the group, the click *expand / collapse* **area** which identifies that group.

**Is there any way to access this row?**

It is *not* present in row data which populates the grid.

```
 this.autoGroupColumnDef = { 
      field: "column",
      headerName: " Column containing the expand / collapse rows ",
      valueGetter:  function nameGetter(params) {
       console.log("All rows: ", params.data); // group rows not present here
       return params.data.nameToDisplay;
      }
    }
```

Comment: provide a sample code for testing, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no clarity with the above code, I can just suggest you to identify which row is a group and which is not.

You can call the `onModelUpdated` which gets called on page load and on any update to the ag-grid.

```
*Example:*

 onModelUpdated = (params) => {
    params.api.forEachNode((node) => {
      if (node.group) {
      console.log('Row data', node);
        } else {
//do nothing
}
    });
  }
```

`node.group` returns either true or false